# How could I encourage my Customers to pay me in Bitcoin?

Tags: invoices

I run a small pharmaceutical business and send PDF Invoices to various accounts payable departments of medium to large businesses monthly. Could I generate a QR code for an on-chain Bitcoin payment and put it on the invoice as an image? Lightning QR code does not seem appropriate because of its expiry as most Accounts Payable depts will take 30 days+ to make a payment. I could self-generate Remittance Advice information by polling my public key using an API? I realise I am living in the future, but I want a practical and provocative way to move Bitcoin forward in my own heavily-fiat world.

Comment: "Moves so slowly... grows so smoothly..." Bitcoin doesn't need you. Let your customers pay with any means they want...